# I am getting an "invalid json for auth config", error

Tags: php, laravel

I am testing a script that I am launching, the script is for a website that  takes in data for an eCommerce website in .json file format, you add .json file in the website, and it display the metrics in a helpful and understandable manner.

Now when I try to add a .json file, I am getting an 500(SERVER ERROR). I checked the APP_DEBUG. and it displayed **"invalid json for auth config"**.
[more detail of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxsB6.png)

I hope the problem is well explained, and understood.

I skimmed through the code, but didn't really find much.

```
 * the "Download JSON" button on in the Google Developer
     * Console.
     * @param string|array $config the configuration json
     * @throws \Google\Exception
     */

    public function setAuthConfig($config)
    {
        if (is_string($config)) {
            if (!file_exists($config)) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('file "%s" does not exist', $config));
            }

            $json = file_get_contents($config);

            if (!$config = json_decode($json, true)) {
                throw new LogicException('invalid json for auth config');
            }
        }

        $key = isset($config['installed']) ? 'installed' : 'web';

        if (isset($config['type']) && $config['type'] == 'service_account') {

            // application default credentials

            $this->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

            // set the information from the config
            $this->setClientId($config['client_id']);
            $this->config['client_email'] = $config['client_email'];

            $this->config['signing_key'] = $config['private_key'];

            $this->config['signing_algorithm'] = 'HS256';

        } elseif (isset($config[$key])) {
```

Comment: The configuration file being passed into setAuthConfig does not contain valid json, so `$config = json_decode($json, true)` fails when it's trying to decode it. You'll need to look at your config file to figure out why.